# Order of channel blocking

Tags: go, channel

I am trying to understand how channels work in golang. The code I have is very simple but the output is surprising.

As the documentation states: reading and writing from/to a channel is blocking the current goroutine, so I thought writing to a channel would block the channel until the main routine yields.

```
package main

func rtn(messages chan<- string) {
    defer close(messages)

    println("p1")
    messages <- "ping1"

    //for i := 0; i < 10000000; i++ { }

    println("p2")
    messages <- "ping2"
}

func main() {
    messages := make(chan string)
    go rtn(messages)

    for msg := range messages {
        println(msg)
    }
}
```

I thought it would print

```
p1
ping1
p2
ping2
```

but it actually prints

```
p1
p2
ping1
ping2
```

Comment: Everything works as expected. Get familiar with Golang concurrency. (eg. [here](https://medium.com/rungo/achieving-concurrency-in-go-3f84cbf870ca))

Comment: Most expectations about the order of concurrent operations are unfounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an unbuffered channels, that works as a point of synchronization between the main and second goroutines.

In this case, you only know that when the second goroutine is here `messages <- "ping1"` the main one is at the line `for msg := range messages`. Thus, there is no guarantee that main loop reaches `println(msg)` immediately. I.e., in the meantime the second goroutine could have moved on and reached lines `println("p2")` and `messages <- "ping2"`.

As a counterexample, I am adding a channel just to enforce the complete synchronization between prints.

```
package main

func rtn(messages chan<- string, syncChan chan struct{}) {
    defer close(messages)

    println("p1")
    messages <- "ping1"

    //Wait for main goroutine to print its message
    <-syncChan

    //for i := 0; i < 10000000; i++ { }

    println("p2")
    messages <- "ping2"

    //Wait for main goroutine to print its message
    <-syncChan
}

func main() {
    messages := make(chan string)
    syncChan := make(chan struct{})
    go rtn(messages, syncChan)

    for msg := range messages {
        println(msg)
        //Notify the second goroutine that is free to go
        syncChan <- struct{}{}
    }
}
```

Which prints the output you expected:

```
p1
ping1
p2
ping2
```

Here is another example that produce the output you are looking for. In this case the main goroutine is forcefully blocked by the `time.Sleep()`. This will make the second goroutine be ready to send before the receiver is ready to receive. Therefore, the sender will actually block on the send operation.

```
package main

import (
    "time"
)

func rtn(messages chan<- string) {
    defer close(messages)

    println("p1")
    messages <- "ping1"

    //for i := 0; i < 10000000; i++ { }

    println("p2")
    messages <- "ping2"
}

func main() {
    messages := make(chan string)
    go rtn(messages)

    //Put main goroutine to sleep. This will make the
    //sender goroutine ready before the receiver. 
    //Therefore it will have to actually block!
    time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 500)

    for msg := range messages {
        println(msg)
    }
}
```

Comment: correct me if Im wrong, you are saying that the second routine is actually working in between `for msg := range messages` and `println(msg)` ? Wan't it supposed to be blocked?

Comment: Why is it supposed to be blocked? The blocking operation is only the `for msg := range messages`. Moreover, for cases like this, there are optimizations that channels do. That is, when there is a goroutine blocked on a channel read and another goroutine sends a new message that would unblock the first one, then the sender directly copies the value into the blocked goroutine. Without really pushing the message into the channel's queue (which does not even exists in case of unbuffered channels). Thus, the sender goroutine does not need to be actually blocked.

Comment: before going further, thanks for taking your time to explain these things.
I got that idea from [https://gobyexample.com/channels] where it said **By default sends and receives block until both the sender and receiver are ready** , so I thought once I write to the channel the main routine will pick it up and would continue working until something blocked (and then the second one would pick up)

Comment: I added a new example to clarify the concept. Basically, the statement above is true. But in your code, the main goroutine is immediately ready to receive from channel. Therefore, the sender will not block because it has nothing to wait for.